# How to paint graphics exported from Illustrator to flash professional

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, adobe-flash

I work doing e learning, and I need to use graphics from pdf manuals. I open the pdf manuals in Illustrators ,and I grab the graphics from there and drag them to flash professional. But when I get the graphic in flash, it's devided in different inner layers , and its a pain to go through each leayer and copy and paste the lines into one layer in order to paint them... is there an easy way of putting them on one layer so that i can paint it with the paint bucket tool???

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the layers in Illustrator before dragging to Flash. Select all layers that you want to merge, and click Unite in the Pathfinder box (the top left one).

[image]

Flash is not that good at handling vector objects as Illustrator so always try to prepare your paths as much as possible in Illustrator before exporting to Flash.